# RavenDb Polymorphism: unable to load a child object?

Tags: nosql, polymorphism, ravendb

Imagine you have the following objects:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal { 
   /* Stuff */ 
}

public class Dog : Animal { 
   /* Stuff */ 
}
```

We store some Cats & Dogs into RavenDb with the following id's:

Cats/1367779b-20c7-466a-a660-46ae7e35c5bd

Dogs/23ef9796-9cdd-4323-88d2-5e5c37881352

If we try to load the objects from the store like this, we have the following behaviour:

```
var id = Guid.Parse("1367779b-20c7-466a-a660-46ae7e35c5bd");
Session.Load<Cat>(id) => returns correct Cat
Session.Load<Animal>("Cats/"+id) => returns correct Cat as an animal

Session.Load<Animal>(id) => returns null ???
```

We really wanted to use the last line, but apparently this doesn't work because of the prefix logic in RavenDb. We've already found a way to avoid this: use a string instead of a guid as Id via the contructor of the objects, like:

```
protected Animal(){
     this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

This removes the prefixes "Cats/" and "Dogs/" completely. Is there a better solution to fix this, so that we can keep the Id as a Guid instead of a string value?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `documentStore.Conventions.RegisterIdConvention` to have effective control on the id generation for specific classes.